# nicer structure to url from mvc beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following formin my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ToolsForHire", FormMethod.Get))
{

    <p>tool required: @Html.TextBox("tool")</p>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
}
```

Submitting this form posts to:

```
localhost:54124/ToolsForHire?tool=mytooltext
```

That all works fine.

However what I'd like to happen is that my url ends up being:

```
localhost:54124/ToolsForHire/mytooltext
```

Still getting to grips with mvc so some advice would be good?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the following BeginForm extension method [BeginForm(action, controller, routevalues, FormMethod)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493084%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Where the routevalues are something along the lines of

```
new {tool = mytooltext}
```

Generally the default routing is set to expect an id optional parameter, so had the routing values been

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ToolsForHire", new {id = mytooltext}, FormMethod.Get))
```

Then the result of the url would be http://localhost/ToolsForHire/[value of mytooltext]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get most what you are saying mytooltext though is the text that was entered into the "tool" textbox, how could i get that into new {id = mytooltext}?

Comment: just to clarify, the "tool" textbox is a textbox on the client side, right? so what you want to happen is provide them with a form and when they populate the "tool" textbox that value will be passed on submit? if that's the case you're going to want to use javascript to update the form action attribute. Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Sorry its taken ages to reply. Yes the "tool" is a textbox. So I want them to enter it, submit and then pass that value as a neat url so it would be url.com/toolsforhire/somevaluefromthetooltextbox

Comment: @Simon if the url needs to be modified from the client side then you'll definitely want to use javascript to handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the url rewriting in the global.ascx.cx file

Comment: Can you expand please maybe with an example?

Comment: Ah!  You can change the Httpget to Httppost  @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ToolsForHire", FormMethod.Post)) and add a parameter with the name (string tool) in your controller